# Excel 2010 COUNTIF Bug

Tags: excel, excel-2010, countif

Hope all is well.

I think I've found a bug in Excel 2010 (running under Windows 7) ...

In cell `A1` I have the datetime value `03/05/2015  02:32:11`

In cell `B1` I have the formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,">"&A1)`

The issue is that the formula is returning 1 when I believe it should be returning a 0.  [There are no other values in column A so there cannot be anything with a value greater than A1 in column A].

Bizarrely, if the *time* in A1 is changed - even by a second - then the formula works (i.e. returns 0) ... but if the *date* is changed it remains incorrect (returning 1) ...!

[BTW: I'm using the UK date format: dd/mm/yyyy]

How can this be?  What is special about this particular time?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Are you sure it's formatted as a datetime?

Comment: Hello Nicholas - Yes it's definately formatted as a datetime.  It seems to be something around using that particular value ...

Comment: Looks like a floating point precision problem to me.